# Get multiple Properties From DataGrid Selection_Change Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

this is my problem

i have a DataGrid and this his source

```
var Query = from a in m.Table1
                       join p in m.Table2
                       on a.Value1 equals p.Value1
                       join c in m.Table3 on a.Value2 equals  c.Value2 
           select new {
                        value1 = a.value1
                        value2 = p.value2
                        value3 = c.value3
                        value4 = a.value4

                      };
```

```xml
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,75,0,0"
 Name="Grid_Exmple" Width="478" Height="219" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="Grid_Exmple_SelectionChanged">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding value1 }" Header="value1 " IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgrvalue1 "  />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding value2 }" Header="value2 " IsReadOnly="True"  x:Name="dgrvalue2 " />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding value3 }" Header="value3 " IsReadOnly="True"  x:Name="dgrvalue3" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding value4}" Header="value4" IsReadOnly="True"  x:Name="dgrvalue4" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

when we press on the DataGrid Selection Event

```
  private void Grid_Exmple_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    Here I try To Get The properties
```

i can see the properties in e.AddedItems but i cant cast it

```
    ((<>f__AnonymousType2<int,int?,decimal?,decimal?,string,string,string,int,string>)(((object[])(e.AddedItems))[0])).Value1

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least two possibilities:

1. Create a named type, fill the grid with that and then cast back to this type.
2. Cast to [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) and do whatever you want.